# External URI Post Gettoken REST SPRING JAVA

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, oauth-2.0

There is a external URI for catching token with `post` request. In its body `uaa-url, client ID, secret` are included. How can I get token? Its related URI is like `{{https:// token...}}/gettoken`.  and This URI is not in my domain. 
I need this `(bearer)token` to be added to the `header` before calling `exchange` method on `restTemplate` instance.

```
"uaaURL":"https://{{abc}}.{{de}}",
"clientID":"id-{{cid_value}}",
"clientSecret":"{{clientSecret_value}}",
"username":"value"
"samlAttributes":{
    "Groups":["{{}}"],
    "attribute1":["vaattr"]
 }
```

Any example/ link etc. would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get that token in real time, you need to really get an access to the token service. However if you need to just test your application, you can mock the request and can create JWT token here:
https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/

Comment: With the body above I should get token from token service. With `POST` request from an external URI. @Ms. Zia

Comment: Try this format:

POST http://[tokenservicehost]/gettoken?client_id=[your_clientid]&client_secret=[your_clientsecret]&grant_type=password&username=[your_username]&password=[your_password]&response_type=token

Comment: what if the `password` value is not available? @Ms. Zia. I do not have this in my body.

Comment: use relevant grant type then (client_credentials looks relevant in your case) . For detail check this link: https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/